# Class 'CodeIgniter\Filters\Logincheck ' not found in Codeignitor 4

Tags: codeigniter-4

Class 'CodeIgniter\Filters\Logincheck' not found

getting this error when try to create an filter to check the users authentication in CI 4.
"Filter Controller":

```
<?php namespace App\Filters;

use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\FilterInterface;

class Logincheck implements FilterInterface
{ 
    public function before(RequestInterface $request)
    {
        // Do something here
            helper('auth');
            if(!logged_in()){
                $redirectURL =  '/';
                return redirect()->to($redirectURL);                                    
            }
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------

    public function after(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response)
    {
        // Do something here
    }
}
```

Steps followed:

Created Filter Class  `Logincheck.php`  in app/Filters
modified the app/config/Filters.php as

```
class Filters extends BaseConfig
{
    // Makes reading things below nicer,
    // and simpler to change out script that's used.
    public $aliases = [
        'Logincheck' => \CodeIgniter\Filters\Logincheck::class,
        'csrf'     => \CodeIgniter\Filters\CSRF::class,
        'toolbar'  => \CodeIgniter\Filters\DebugToolbar::class,
        'honeypot' => \CodeIgniter\Filters\Honeypot::class,
    ]; 

    // Always applied before every request
    public $globals = [
        'before' => [
            'Logincheck'
            //'honeypot'
            // 'csrf',
        ],
        'after'  => [
            'toolbar',
            //'honeypot'
        ],
    ];
```

after doing this when I am firing the controller getting the error as :

```
SYSTEMPATH/Filters/Filters.php at line 164

157             else
158             {
159                 $classNames = [$this->config->aliases[$alias]];
160             }
161 
162             foreach ($classNames as $className)
163             {
164                 $class = new $className();
165 
166                 if (! $class instanceof FilterInterface)
167                 {
168                     throw FilterException::forIncorrectInterface(get_class($class));
169                 }
170 
171                 if ($position === 'before')
```

Comment: Can you provide us the code of your filter? Your error might come from it.

Comment: added the filter code in the question description.   please check once.

Comment: 'Logincheck' => \CodeIgniter\Filters\Logincheck::class, Is the problem. Your code is in \App\Filters so you need to replace CodeIgniter with App.

Comment: changed it to destined location - public $aliases = [
  'Logincheck' => \App\Filters\Logincheck::class,     it is going for "too many redirects"

Comment: Then your problem is not the same anymore. Your error means that your filter is loaded correctly.

Comment: ok, but checking further the internal redirect code, i found it as working perfect in other normal controller positions.

Comment: so now i understand the problem, filter has started to work, but redirect to the controller is again calling the same filter to check login->which is again calling the same filter in loop. So now I have to certain package in the exclusion list of Fliter ->  public $globals = [
  'before' => [
   'Logincheck' => ['except' => 'auth\*']  -- but i think it not getting pointed at correct path (Currently my auth module in in vendord/auth/ location), any help please ?

Comment: What do you mean certain package ? Filter works on routes as far as I know.

Comment: package can be anything like login or registration. Filter config have the exclusion option where you can exclude the packages you do not wish to apply your filter with.

Comment: It doesn't work like that. Filters work on URI patterns not on the packages. https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/filters.html?highlight=filters

Comment: agreed. i meant to say URI only but was by mistake calling it as a package.

Comment: I don't know the structure of your Auth, but chances are it provides the implementation rather than URI. Hence you may need to build an endpoint to handle authentication.

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare the correct path of your defined filter location.
As in your case you have declared it in App/Filters directory so your path must be like below

```
public $aliases = [
    'csrf'     => \CodeIgniter\Filters\CSRF::class,
    'toolbar'  => \CodeIgniter\Filters\DebugToolbar::class,
    'honeypot' => \CodeIgniter\Filters\Honeypot::class,
    'Logincheck'=>\App\Filters\ Logincheck::class,
];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create the filter in your app folder maybe the problem is the route

```
use App\Filters\FilterInterface;
'honeypot' => \App\Filters\Honeypot::class,
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare aliases "Logincheck" in small example:- **logincheck**

```
 public $aliases = [
        'Logincheck' => \CodeIgniter\Filters\Logincheck::class,
        'csrf'     => \CodeIgniter\Filters\CSRF::class,
        'toolbar'  => \CodeIgniter\Filters\DebugToolbar::class,
        'honeypot' => \CodeIgniter\Filters\Honeypot::class,
    ];
```